# Function to change the Highcharts fontSize

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to change the fontSize using a jQuery function?

I tried using this code:

```
$('#container').highcharts().container.parentNode.style.fontSize = '40px';
```

I found on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/rcncL/

But did not work, I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined
```

No luck for me :(

Comment: Is `container` the id of your graph div?

Comment: Yes, it is, it's the id.

Answer (score 0):

$("#container").highcharts({ chart : style: {
    fontSize: '12px'
}});

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not. Got an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :", I edited a little:  "$("#container").highcharts({ chart: { style: { fontSize: '1px' } } });" , but still did not change anything on the charts :(, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '40px'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but, where do I call it and how do I say that's for one specific chart? I mean, I want to change it outside, like clicking on a button and it change the chart font size. I know how to edit it inside the chart options.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple way, you can set useHTML flag in any place which use text (like labels, titles) and then return text wrapped in div object with the class.

```
 $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('.fontsize').css({
            'font-size': '20px'
        })
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4Qxz/2/

Comment: Bo luck, but thanks, I think it's impossible to do it.